# Email two queries as Excel attachments in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

How can I email two queries as attachments in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Currently my code is only for one query. Thank you

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmailDailyMembers]
AS
    DECLARE @attach_query_result_as_file BIT = 1 -- yes, attach results as file  
    DECLARE @query_result_header BIT = 1 -- include column headers  
    DECLARE @query_result_separator CHAR(1) = char(9)
    DECLARE @recordCount int 

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
              @recipients = 'aaa@gmail.com',
              @subject = 'Report1', 
              @query_attachment_filename = 'Report1.csv',  
              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, -- attach as a file, csv in this case   
              @query_result_separator = @query_result_separator, 
              @query = 'USE Revenue2 SELECT * FROM [Membership Report]',
              @query_result_header = 1,
              @query_result_no_padding = 1,
              @exclude_query_output = 1
END
```

Comment: What happens if you try `@query = 'SELECT * FROM Table 1; SELECT * FROM Table2;'`

Comment: Similar question answered for already prepared files - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/152131/31052


Suggestion . Take advantage of `@execute_query_database`


Full documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15